# If a record doesn't not exist in table (filters applied), I want my && function to return 1 in DAX measure

Tags: dax, not-exists

[I have added image which will describe data and matrix i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzlN7.png)

I have to use simple DAX to show if vehicle has taken a trip and it has not refueled that day. So it should return 1 in my measure.

I am using IF Table 1[Miles]>1 && Table2 [fuel]<0 , it should return 1, filters (Date and Vehicle Number). it returns blank in my matrix

The day vehicle doesnt refill , no record is entered, so if i check data behind, apply date filter , i donot get any rows.

I want my DAX to return 1 if it doesnt find any record

Comment: Please post sample data in text format along with expected output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I have added image , which will show data and matrix i want

Comment: @Saira what you mean Table2[fuel]<0 ? According to your dataset, no value meets the condition, and It is normal for it to return empty values.

Comment: fuel can be (<0) ? -5 , -10 ? If It is finished and not refueled, then It should be 0.

Comment: Yes, if it is not refueled, it will not be recorded. Whenever fuel card is used, that is when fuel data is entered, basically , if it is not refueled, it should be recorded as zero, but unfortunately software doesn't work this way. I know Table2[fuel]<0 will not work, so, i tried iferror, iserror as well , but it doesnt return 1

Answer (score 0):

According to the fuel not being negative, At most zero, and based on this condition:

Here is the relationship formed [Vehicle ID]:

[image: Relformed]

Also you need to enter data for Car ID2 Fuel information:

[image: DFERE]

Now You need to create your measure to use in matrix visual:

```
YourMeasure = CALCULATE(
    SUMX('Data Table2',
        IF(RELATED('Data Table1'[Miles])>1 && 'Data Table2'[Fuel]= 0, 1)))
```

And finally test it on the visual:

[image: hyjyjjyjy]

Comment: Hi Ozan, i donot want to enter fuel data manually. As, fuel data is collected by software each time fuel card is used. Is there any way my measure can return 1 if it doesnt find any record for fuel on 2.9.2022 . Any DAX that returns 1 for missing record

Comment: I am afraid 'No'. This is not the way DAX works. Let's test it: write in the  2nd if condition: 'Data Table2'[Fuel] = BLANK() instead of  'Data Table2'[Fuel]= 0. The result will show empty cells. Now It is my time to ask a question: How does DAX will know fuel column value for Car2 is empty or BLANK() or 0 or NULL , or even Unknown? If data is collected by software, then before putting data in Power BI storage space, You need an ETL to do the job for you: It means Add that row logically.

Comment: Thanks Ozan , I spent alot of time using all different functions i could find. It kind of confirms that it has to done by ETL .